# md-datepicker does not works with touch screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker

I am building an application for a multi-touchscreen and wanted to use the angular material datepicker.

Even though it works fine when using it with a normal mouse, when I tried using it on my touchscreen, the datepicker is not scrollable. I do not really know what I am doing wrong, as the examples on the angular material page are working.

So this is the code: (I kind of tried it everywhere on my page, so it does not really matter what is around this code as it did not work anywhere else as well):

```
 <div style="margin-top: 10px">
   <h5>Daterange:</h5>
   <md-datepicker style="padding-right: 0px; margin-right: 18px" md-placeholder="From" ng-model="searchStartDate" md-max-date="searchEndDate" ng-change="clearShipSearch(); shipSearch()"></md-datepicker>
                        -
   <md-datepicker md-placeholder="To" ng-model="searchEndDate" md-min-date="searchStartDate" ng-change="clearShipSearch(); shipSearch()"></md-datepicker>
</div>
```